# How to inject Verilog code in Chisel generated Module?

Tags: hdl, chisel, yosys, cocotb

To test my Chisel designs I'm using [Icarus](https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog) with [cocotb](https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb). But Icarus doesn't generate VCD traces if it's not asked explicitly in verilog module code like this :

```
`ifdef COCOTB_SIM
initial begin
  $dumpfile ("my_module_name.vcd");
  $dumpvars (0, my_module_name);
  #1;
end
`endif
```

To add this each time I generate my chisel module, I wrote a little python script named [cocotbify.py](https://github.com/Martoni/chisverilogutils/tree/master/cocotbify) that "inject" this code under the module generated.

Similarly, to add some systemVerilog assert()/assume() for Formal checking with [yosys-smtbmc](http://www.clifford.at/papers/2017/smtbmc-sby/slides.pdf) I have to "inject" code under each verilog modules generated. I also hacked a little python script named [smtbmcify.py](https://github.com/Martoni/chisverilogutils/tree/master/smtbmcify) to inject my assert/assume codes.

I realize that is a hack, but I can't found a good way to do it directly under the Chisel module. I know that there are [BlackBox](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/BlackBoxes), but I don't wan't to instanciate a submodule, and the function setInline create a second verilog file (I want to write in module directly).

I saw a type named [ChiselAnnotation](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/annotations.html) in Chisel scala code, But I'm not sure that is the things to use and I don't now how.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I have been trying to resolve the same.

Comment: no, I still use my hacky python script "cocotbify.py". But I'm still interested by the solution :)

Comment: maybe if I ever have some free time I can look into a firrtl transform and update :)